# How to get next post ID?

Tags: posts, id

Here is [get_next_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post) function. But it gets next post only in main query. I want to get next post id by current ID. ie. my current id is `456` and get `nextPostId('456')` it must return `457`

Is it possible?

Comment: There's no guarantee that the next ID is even a post. It could easily be a revision or nav menu item. So unless it doesn't matter you're going to need *some* sort of criteria to use to find the 'next post'. So if it's not the next post in the query, what is it?

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324421/getting-next-previous-post-id-using-current-post-id-in-wordpress